# next page link need to find python

Tags: python, html, python-2.7

I want to know how Im able to find the next page link the script is given below

there is main div class="abc" that covers the next page link which is

```
  www.abc.com #base url
  www.abc.com/options/latest/121?n=0
```

able to collect options url and get the details from it. this page conatins the next page link which is

```
<p>  <a href="/options/latest/121?n=20">suivant »</a> </p>
```

im able to get this link and also details from it but not able to collect the next page from the

```
<p>  <a href="/options/latest/121?n=20">suivant »</a> </p>
```

want to collect

```
 <p>  <a href="/options/latest/121?n=40">suivant »</a> </p>
```

want to go until last page

Comment: what is the real site?

Comment: I dont want to disclose just i want to know how to switch next page else im able to collect the required info. the only thing at every page is providing the next page link only "not the last page link".

Answer (score 1):

To get the next url from html page, you could use [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
import re

def get_next_url(soup):
    for div in soup.find_all('div', 'abc'):
        a = div.find('a', href=re.compile('^/options/latest/'),
                     text=re.compile('suivant'))
        if a is not None:
           return a['href']
```

To switch to the next page:

```
from urllib2 import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # $ pip install beautifulsoup4

link = '/first/page'
while link:
    print(link)
    page = urlopen('http://example.com' + link)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, from_encoding=page.info().getparam('charset'))
    link = get_next_url(soup)
```

Comment: im trying to test but this line text=re.compile('suivant')) showing syntax error

Comment: now im able to run sucessfully but actually i have some more next pages so i need to know how i can manage to get all those ?

Comment: the `while` loop prints all urls that start with `'/options/latest/'`, have the word `'suivant'` in their text, and that are inside `<div class="abc">` (one per div).

Comment: <a href="/options/latest/?n=20">suivant »</a> this is the only link contains by each page so need to switch this page then collect the next page link which is  <a href="/options/latest/?n=40">suivant »</a>

Comment: what is the first page url? [add it your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/23041456/edit).

Comment: i changed my question check it out thnx

Comment: @user3528727: how does the code from my answer fail in your case?

Comment: its working but i already done with this part i just need to know how i can switch to next pages.